# I need the method to return all values from the select query

Tags: java, mysql, return-type

My project requires me to retrieve data from a mySQL database. The method is contained in a class that contains dozens of other database access methods for my java program. The plan is to call this methods from any other class that requires the data from the database. The problem is in java you can only return one data type and yet I need to get back all data from the tuple obtained.

What is the best way to get my method to return (in another class that calls this method) all the data from my query?

Here's the code snippet:

```
// SELECT QUERIES 
public void select_H_Customer_Table(int get_intCustomerID) { 
  int intCustomerID = get_intCustomerID; 
  sql = "SELECT intCustomerID, vachCustomerTitle, vachCustomerFirstName, vachCustomerSurnames, dteCustomerDOB, vachCustomerAddressStreet, vachCustomerAddressTown, vachCustomerAddressCounty, vachCustomerAddressPostalCode, intCustomerHomePhone, intCustomerWorkPhone, intCustomerMobilePhone, vachCustomerEmail FROM h_customers " + "WHERE" + " intCustomerID=?"; 
   try {
     st.setInt(1, intCustomerID); 
     rs = st.executeQuery(); 
     while (rs.next()){ 
       int rs_intCustomerID = rs.getInt("intCustomerID"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerTitle = rs.getString("vachCustomerTitle");            
       String rs_vachCustomerFirstName = rs.getString("vachCustomerFirstName"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerSurnames = rs.getString("vachCustomerSurnames"); 
       String rs_dteCustomerDOB = rs.getString("dteCustomerDOB"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerAddressStreet = rs.getString("vachCustomerAddressStreet"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerAddressTown = rs.getString("vachCustomerAddressTown"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerAddressCounty = rs.getString("vachCustomerAddressCounty"); 
       String rs_vachCustomerAddressPostalCode = rs.getString("vachCustomerAddressPostalCode"); 
       int rs_intCustomerHomePhone = rs.getInt("intCustomerHomePhone"); 
       int rs_intCustomerWorkPhone = rs.getInt("intCustomerWorkPhone"); 
       int rs_intCustomerMobilePhone = rs.getInt("intCustomerMobilePhone");
       String rs_txtCustomerEmail = rs.getString("txtCustomerEmail"); 
    } 
  } catch (SQLException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: You only said "you can only return one data type".  Let that datatype be you custom object.  Create a class of you own to wrap the content that you fetch from the database and return that object.  In some cases you could use Map object with column name as Key and respective column value as Map value

Comment: please reformat your code snippet so that it's not just a 1000 characters comment. The markdown editor has code formatting, so you can have it neatly displayed easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `Customer` class and the query method have to return a `Customer`

The object Customer should be like:

`class Customer {
    public Customer() {};
    private int iD; 
    private String title; 
    private String firstName; 
    private String surnames; 
    private String dOB; 
    private String addressStreet; 
    private String addressTown; 
    private String addressCounty; 
    private String addressPostalCode; 
    private int homePhone; 
    private int workPhone; 
    private int mobilePhone; 
    private String customerEmail; 
    // Generate getters and setters
}`

And the query method should be:

```
public Customer getCustomerById(int customerID) {

    String sql = "SELECT intCustomerID, vachCustomerTitle, vachCustomerFirstName, vachCustomerSurnames, dteCustomerDOB, vachCustomerAddressStreet, vachCustomerAddressTown, vachCustomerAddressCounty, vachCustomerAddressPostalCode, intCustomerHomePhone, intCustomerWorkPhone, intCustomerMobilePhone, vachCustomerEmail FROM h_customers " + "WHERE" + " intCustomerID=?"; 
    try { 
        st.setInt(1, customerID); 
        rs = st.executeQuery(); 
        while (rs.next()){ 
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(rs.getInt("intCustomerID")); 
            customer.setTitle(rs.getString("vachCustomerTitle")); 
            customer.setFirstName(rs.getString("vachCustomerFirstName")); 
            //...
            return customer;
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } }
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method takes a customer ID as a parameter, so there should be no need to return a list of Customer objects. But I would suggest to change to name of the method to something like 
`public Customer getCustomerById (int customerId)`

Comment: You are right. I was confused with the original method name. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help Diego & @shikjohari, may I ask how I'll retrieve the data returned and assign it to a variable, should I use a list or array?

Comment: It's better to use a List because use dynamic memory and you don't need to know the size of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Create a pojo (an entity class) and use select * query. Once you have the resultset create the object of pojo and populate the fields and return

```
public class MyData{
   private String name;
   private String desc;
   //constructor or setter getter
}
```

And once you have the resultset create `new MyData()` with the fields

```
MyData data = null;
while(resultSet.next()){
  data = new MyData(resultSet.getString("NAME"), resultSet.getString("DESC"));
}
return data;
```

Something like this !!!
If you have a lot of fields, I would prefer setters and getters instead of the parameterized constructor

Comment: FYI : "pojo" stands for Plain Old Java Object

Comment: Should the pojo be an external or nested class?

Comment: depends on how you want to use it. If you want to use it in other class as well then make it as a separate public class